# Network interface keeps resetting, dmesg errors

Tags: networking, dmesg, navigation

Every five-ten seconds the network interface keeps reconfiguring, resulting in a continuous error from "network changed" in the browsers and a continuous output from dmesg that keeps repeating

```
br-f5142f657454: port 2(veth38df841) entered blocking state
[   86.477703] br-f5142f657454: port 2(veth38df841) entered disabled state
[   86.477731] veth38df841: entered allmulticast mode
[   86.478211] veth38df841: entered promiscuous mode
[   86.644747] eth0: renamed from veth40e3a7f
[   86.676631] br-f5142f657454: port 2(veth38df841) entered blocking state
[   86.676644] br-f5142f657454: port 2(veth38df841) entered forwarding state
[   88.577166] br-f5142f657454: port 2(veth38df841) entered disabled state
[   88.577226] veth40e3a7f: renamed from eth0
[   88.648223] br-f5142f657454: port 2(veth38df841) entered disabled state
[   88.648872] veth38df841 (unregistering): left allmulticast mode
[   88.648876] veth38df841 (unregistering): left promiscuous mode
[   88.648879] br-f5142f657454: port 2(veth38df841) entered disabled state
[   88.730167] evict_inodes inode 00000000797864b1, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730177] evict_inodes inode 000000004f0f3373, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730179] evict_inodes inode 00000000ffe366a5, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730181] evict_inodes inode 00000000a00ffe8b, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730183] evict_inodes inode 000000009aafa27a, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730185] evict_inodes inode 0000000094474afc, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730187] evict_inodes inode 000000009dfaace4, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730189] evict_inodes inode 0000000008b2ee7a, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730191] evict_inodes inode 00000000bac33c85, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730193] evict_inodes inode 00000000eb1497fb, i_count = 1, was skipped!
[   88.730195] evict_inodes inode 0000000051a967ee, i_count = 1, was skipped!
```

It goes on and on with the same output every approximately ten seconds.
My pc is a Lenovo X1 Carbon 9th gen and it has network interfaces for wifi, docker and zerotier.

I could't find anything online about this problem and I'm not sure on what to look for.
Thank you all in advance for your help

EDIT:
Uninstalled zerotier and still having the same problem

EDIT:
For further information I was using Ubuntu 23.10.

I've found and solved the problem removing Kasm Workspace. Unfortunately I've no more time to investigate this issue but still wanted to share that uninstalling Kasm and its docker images stopped the problem on my network interface.

Comment: The "veth[...] {allmulticast,promiscuous} mode" suggests userspace is messing with that interface. I would check in your zerotier logs

Comment: @DanielT Unfortunately I've uninstalled zerotier and have still the same problem

Comment: What is `veth38df841` from? This name looks like something that software created, and doesn't look like a hardware device

Comment: @DanielT those are from a VM.   ... also seems to me an important part of the problem: There is a VM used?

Comment: @Rinzwind unfortunately I've no VM installed, using only docker on this machine

Comment: @DanieleGamba same issue: that is crucial info for the question...

Comment: Should I try to remove docker? I temporarily can. Otherwise how can I investigate what crated that virtual card?